# Scanning feature in Alfresco community edition?

Tags: java, alfresco, scanning, alfresco-share

I am working on to the  alfresco 4.2 community addition.now i have to use the some kind of Scanning feature  to scan the hard copy of the document and upload.

I have googled but haven't found any good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @zladuric:s answer I would like to add that there are software like Ephesoft and Kofax that for example can aid in the extraction of metadata from the scanned documents.

Comment: I have installed ephesoft community version on my system and tried to work on to the web scaner. But when i click on to the webscaner tab it shows me blank page and a error in to the console ie

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - localhost:8082/dcma/webscanner/webscanner.nocache.js"

.

I have downloaded the source code of epchesoft from https://code.google.com/p/ephesoft/ and tried to search webscanner.nocache.js in source code folder and havent found any thing.

Is there any solution for this.

Comment: The web scanning is just with the enterprise edition

Answer (score 6):

Additionally to Alfresco you need a so called capture software which handles the scanning, converting to a PDF, OCR and the filing to Alfresco. There are several solutions available in in the market in different quality with different concepts.

Here a (not complete) list of working solutions I know of in the order of costs:

- [Quikdrop](https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/quikdrop-alfresco) (Client-Installation): simple .NET-Client with Scan-Client, PDF-Conversion, OCR and limited Metadata-Support
- [Kofax-Express with Alfresco-Connector from ic-solution](http://www.ecm-market.de/scan-client-fur-alfresco.html) (Client-Installation): professional Capture Client supporting barcodes, scan optimizations, guided metadata extraction, validations, delivery to Alfresco supporting document types & metadata
- [Ephesoft](http://www.alfresco.com/products/integrations/ephesoft) (Server-Installation): web based capture solution available as a community, cloud and commercial version
- Abbyy Flexicapture (Server-Installation): Local Capture Clients with a central Capture / Transformation and Extraction Service
- Kofax with Alfresco-Kofax-Connector (Server-Installation): Local Capture Clients with a central Capture / Transformation and Extraction Service

Comment: @heiko Robert   thanks for your reply

I have installed ephesoft community version on my system and tried to work on to the web scaner. But when i click on to the webscaner tab it shows me blank page and a error in to the console ie

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - localhost:8082/dcma/webscanner/webscanner.nocache.js"

.

I have downloaded the source code of epchesoft from https://code.google.com/p/ephesoft/ and tried to search webscanner.nocache.js in source code folder and havent found any thing.

Is there any solution for this.

Comment: Can you, please, tell me where to find Alfresco-Kofax-Connector? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Max: There are several depending from the Kofax product: 
- http://services.kofax.com/software/capture/export-connectors-partners.php
- https://www.ecm-market.de/alfresco-module/kofax-express-export-connector-alfresco.html?___store=english

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is probably not related directly to Alfresco. Alfresco is excellent at managing documents, but not until you get them into Alfresco.

So first you have to scan the documents by a scanner and really any scanning software out there. Once you do, you upload the documents using something like:

1. CIFS - you just mount a folder in Alfresco to your desktop, as any other network drive and move the scanned documents in that folder. Usually you'll create an Alfresco rule on that folder to move the documents away, to email somebody, start a workflow or anything really.
2. You can upload the documents using Explorer or Share. It is probably not efficient if you have a lot of documents to upload.
3. You can use another application to connect to Alfresco using the upload API and send the documents in.
4. You email the scanned documents to Alfresco (provided that you have configured up incomming email box on Alfresco).
5. Use Alfrescos built-in FTP server to upload the documents.

There are more ways to get the documents in, these are, I think, the common ones.

Comment: Just as a sample use case: we used PowerScan from Iris to scan stuff. The operator would also do the indexing and some OCR, powerscan would then prepare the XML with this OCR-ed data for us. Then we would copy the XML and PDFs to Alfresco via CIFS (Alfresco space mounted as a "web folder" on the operators' desktop). Alfresco would, upon getting the XML, trigger a rule which picked all the info, converted the PDF to a desired content type, fill the properties from the XML etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ChronoScan (http://www.chronoscan.org) there is a CMIS module to scan/ocr and send directly to Alfresco, SharePoint, etc in PDF Text or other formats,

The software is free for no commercial use with a nag screen, and is very similar to x10 price solutions (Kofax Express, etc..)

Regards

Comment: Don't confuse people! It always requires to upgrade which is very annoying!